# Regular Expression how to stop at first match

Tags: regex

My regex pattern looks like this:

```
(?<=_)(.*?)(?=_)
```

I want replace only the first match between the two underscores (its not allways AVVI, it can be different. Same as AVVIDI):

```
T_AVVI_EINZELPOSTEN_TEST -> T_AVVIDI_EINZELPOSTEN_TEST
```

My regex pattern matches AVVI and EINZEPLOSTEN. How can i modify my regex to find only the first match AVVI?

code:

```
 private Identifier addPrefix(final Identifier identifier) {
    if (isExcluded(identifier)) {
        return identifier;
    }

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=_)(.*?)(?=_)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(identifier.getText());

    return Identifier.toIdentifier(m.replaceAll(prefix)); 
}
```

Comment: Could be good to show us your code that uses this regexp. Seems like you're using `g` flag and you should remove it.

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: OP's attempt of look-arounds with the requirement of `first match between the two underscores` is completely different from the dupe link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `.replaceFirst` like this using start anchor and a capture group:

```bash
String line = identifier.getText()
             .repalceFirst("^([^_]*_)[^_]*(?=_)", "$1AVVIDI");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP2wIS/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `([^_]*_)`: Capture group #1 to match 0 or more chars that are not `_` followed by a `_`
- `[^_]*`: Match 0 or more chars that are not `_`
- `(?=_)`: Positive lookahead to assert presence of `_` at next position
- `$1AVVIDI`: to replace with value in capture group #1 followed by text `AVVIDI`